# Physics does not work on the first frame (_Ready(), _Process(), _PhysicsProcess())

Tags: c#, godot

```
public override void _Process(float delta)
{
    test = area.GetOverlappingAreas();
    GD.Print(test.Count);
}
```

**yields 0 on the 1st frame but works correctly on the 2nd frame.**

I need to get a list of all overlapping objects as the game begins.
I've also encountered this same limitation when trying to Raycast on the first frame.

Comment: If you have only one object how can it overlap with a second object?  There is no second object.

Comment: There are multiple objects.  My problem is that the overlapping works on the 2nd frame but not the first.

Comment: How many object are in the first frame?

Comment: As many objects as there is in the scene.  I manually added all of the objects to the scene. + This happens with any number of objects

Comment: Do any of the objects really overlap.  You first have to understand the geometry and see if the items really overlap or your algorithm to determine overlap is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens with `GetOverlappingAreas` is that it is updated on the physics frame. Furthermore, in `_physics_process` you get the results from the last physics frame.

The documentation says:

> For performance reasons (collisions are all processed at the same time) this list is modified once during the physics step, not immediately after objects are moved. Consider using signals instead.

And that is what you would usually do: use signals. You can use signals to keep track of areas that enter and exit your area.

---

You say:

> I need to get a list of all overlapping objects as the game begins

Yeah, no. But we can get close to it.

I want to point out that when `_ready` of the root of the main scene run, every child node has already loaded. There are plenty of opportunities to run code before that. However, `_ready` is as close to what you want as you get by default.

What you could try is wait a physics frame. For example, you can do this:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    set_process(false) # disable _process
    set_physics_process(false) # disable _physics_process
    yield(get_tree(), "physics_frame") # wait a physics frame
    var test = area.get_overlapping_areas()
    print(test.size())
    set_process(true) # enable _process
    set_physics_process(true) # enable _physics_process
```

Right, C#:

```
public override async void _Ready()
{
    SetProcess(false); # disable _Process
    SetPhysicsProcess(false); # disable _Physics_process
    await ToSignal(GetTree(), "physics_frame"); # wait a physics frame
    var test = area.GetOverlappingAreas();
    GD.Print(test.Count);
    SetProcess(true); # enable _Process
    SetPhysicsProcess(true); # enable _Physics_process
}
```

*If you need to wait multiple physics frames, just repeat the line to wait one physics frame.*

Ok, but, the game should not have been started, right, so we don't only have to do this for the `Node` at hand, but for everything.

So perhaps let us leave this approach behind and do something else…

---

The issue is that `GetOverlappingAreas` is a cached result. You could, instead, make a physics query. Something like this:

```
var query = new PhysicsShapeQueryParameters();
query.CollideWithAreas = true;
query.CollideWithBodies = false;
query.Transform = GlobalTransform;
query.SetShape(area.get_node("CollisionShape").Shape);
var test = GetWorld().DirectSpaceState.CollideShape(query);
GD.Print(test.Count);
```

---

You say:

> I've also encountered this same limitation when trying to Raycast on the first frame.

It is basically the same deal. However, you can force update the `Raycast`s, in this case with `ForceRaycastUpdate`.

Or, you can use a physics query. That would be like this:

```
GD.Print(GetWorld().DirectSpaceState.IntersectRay(from, to));
```

Comment: Fantastic writeup!  Thank you so much, I learned a lot from that

Comment: Also, would it be more performant to use signals versus a physics query?  And if so, are signals reliable enough?  Will enter and exit always be called, even if an object gets deleted or spawned inside another Area?

Comment: @DezBoyle Yes, the signals are reliable. Perhaps too reliable. You get an exited signal if the object was removed from the scene tree (for example to be freed from memory) while it was inside the area. And you will also get the entered signal when an object is added to scene tree inside the area (even if the next line is setting the position outside the area, which would cause an exited signal). I'm not sure about performance. Which reminds me, Godot has a profiler, try it out.